# Creation of Azure Storage account failed with Error message - Subscription was not found

Tags: azure, storage, subscription, account

### Creation of Azure Storage account failed with Error message - Subscription was not found.

Subscription Details:
Subscription Type: Free Tier

Account Balance: more than $190

### Number of Storage Account: Creating First Time.

I was able to find the issue,

Subscriptions -> Resource providers -> Microsoft.Storage

Status: Registering

What I tried to fix:

1. Tried re-register, unregister.
2. Through PowerShell - Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Storage

But the status "Registering" is not changing to "Registered".

However, other registered services, I'm able to create Web apps, SQL db etc.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards,
Vara

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, maybe you should create a support request(**free**) to get more help.

On the `new support request` page, select Issue type as "`Quota`" and Quota type as "`Storage:ARM`", in step 2, write your description to the `details`.

Please follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request) to create support request.